# How to get/generate Charts for our Chatbot using C# CoreBot?

Tags: c#, botframework, data-visualization, chatbot

Receiving Data from our SQL Database hosted in Azure.

Does anyone has an idea how to generate a chart from this data, we could send the user back via the Chatbot?
Any suggested Tools?

Thanks.

Comment: There is little to nothing to go with here. Can you outline what you've attempted?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes we get JSON from our SQL Request. Data about the Oktoberfest e.g. How much beer is drunken on the Oktoberfest? --> We would like to get a Chart visualizing the data in e.g. a barchart --> x axis = Years, y axis = Amount of Beer. We just want to get some ideas we could solve our visualization Problem. Dont know how to start.

Comment: For generating static charts there is image-charts.com for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the basic information provided (I kind of understand the context as I am working on something similar), the simplest way would be to use MS recommend adaptive cards.

http://adaptivecards.io

If I were you, I would pull the data into some backend service (or directly into the bot code itself, its up to you), format it into an adaptive card which contains your chart, and present it to user.

While you can generate charts anyway you want, the challenge would be, how are you going to show it to the user. My suggestion would be to give a link to location where the chart can be viewed.

another would be to generate an image of the chart, and then link that image to an online chart where it is available to view and interact.

How you would generate and present the chart is really up to you.

But, I dont think there is a direct way to generate and present an interactive chart right there in the chat box.

Comment: Hi, thanks it doesnt have to be interactive. For the first demo we used Quickchart.io, where you can create simple charts represented as PNG files. I think it works really good.